# Как заполнить таблицу в Postgresql данными, получаемыми от клиента через Postman? (Язык Go)

Tags: postgresql, golang, request, table, postman

На интернет-ресурсах видел много разных способов как можно заполнить таблицу данными, которые мы записываем сами, но совсем не вижу способов, как сделать автозаполнение таких таблиц.

Например, у меня есть таблица Products, 3 столбца (название, вес, объем)

В Postman я отправляю Post запрос в json название, вес и объем и мне нужно, чтобы эти данные сами вписались в таблицу на Postgreql. Как можно это сделать? Заранее спасибо

```
type (
    BlockRequest struct {
        MerchantID         string `json:"merchantID"`
        MerchantContractID int    `json:"merchantContractID"`
        Card               Card   `json:"card"`
        Amount             int    `json:"amount"`
        OrderID            string `json:"orderID"`
    }

func (br BlockRequest) GetData() error {

    //connect...
    connStr := "user=postgres password=йцукен7 dbname=payment sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    //добавление...
    result, err := db.Exec("insert into merchants (merchant_id, merchant_contract_id, order_id) values ($0, $1, $2)",
        br.MerchantID, br.MerchantContractID, br.OrderID)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result.LastInsertId()) // не поддерживается
    fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected())

    // запрос инфы...
    rows, err := db.Query("select * from merchants")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    merchants := []BlockRequest{}

    //просмотр строк...
    for rows.Next() {
        b := BlockRequest{}
        err := rows.Scan(&b.MerchantID, &b.MerchantContractID, &b.OrderID)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        merchants = append(merchants, b)
    }
    for _, b := range merchants {
        fmt.Println(b.MerchantID, b.MerchantContractID, b.OrderID)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: 1. реализуем получение данных. сделано? 
 2. реализуем запись данных в базу. 

вопрос слишком общий, чтобы дать ответ. лучше приведите кусок кода, который не работает и мы поможем

Comment: привел пример кода, пытался воспользоваться функцией Exec, но я так понимаю с ее помощью я могу внести данные в базу только вручную и запросы из постмана она игнорирует

Comment: не могли бы еще показать как мы получаете данные по rest-у и передается на сохранение в базу?

Comment: дело в том, что на данный момент это все что есть и думал я сохраняю данные в базе автоматически через insert в функции Exec. А получение данных еще не делал, но предполагаю что выводить таблицу буду через Query и методом Get в postman внося параметры. Но хотелось бы конечно получать данные не внося новый handler

Comment: обновил код, на данный момент выдает ошибку No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. upd: понял, что проблема с добавлением (db. Exec) именно после этого действия происходит паника

Answer (score 0):

я не смог бы дать точный ответ что у вас не работает. Поэтому решил написать для вас пример.

создаем таблицу с пользователями

```
create table users
(
    id int
        constraint users_pk
            primary key,
    name varchar(32),
    age int
);
```

вот весь рабочий код

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

type User struct {
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

func JSONError(w http.ResponseWriter, err error, bcode string, code int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff")
    w.WriteHeader(code)
    // nolint: errcheck
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(struct {
        Code    string
        Message string
    }{
        Code:    bcode,
        Message: err.Error(),
    })
}

func (u *User) Save() {
    // connect...
    connStr := "user=user password=password dbname=metrics sslmode=disable port=5432 host=localhost"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // добавление...
    // returning id вернет нужный ID для этого row.
    // так уж получилось, что я сам задаю этот ID. но вы можете использовать автоинкримент
    lastInsertId := 0
    err = db.QueryRow("insert into users (id, name, age) values ($1, $2, $3) returning id",
        u.Id, u.Name, u.Age).Scan(&lastInsertId)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

func (u *User) List() []User {
    // connect...
    connStr := "user=user password=password dbname=metrics sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("select * from users")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    users := []User{}

    // просмотр строк...
    for rows.Next() {
        u := User{}
        err := rows.Scan(&u.Id, &u.Name, &u.Age)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            continue
        }
        users = append(users, u)
    }
    for _, u := range users {
        fmt.Println(u.Id, u.Name, u.Age)
    }

    return users
}

func myHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

    var user User

    err := json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&user)
    if err != nil {
        JSONError(rw, fmt.Errorf("cannot unmarshal user: %w", err), "custom_code", http.StatusUnprocessableEntity)
        return // завершаем выполнение
    }

    user.Save()

    listOfAllUsers := user.List()

    response := struct {
        Users []User
    }{
        listOfAllUsers,
    }

    err = json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(&response)
    if err != nil {
        // тут уже вам решать, что сделать надо
        JSONError(rw, fmt.Errorf("cannot unmarshal response: %w", err), "custom_code2", http.StatusInternalServerError)

        return
    }

    // запишем новый статус в ответ.
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)

    // а если дошли сюда - это значит, что все хорошо. завершаем
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/users", myHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

запускаем приложение и тестируем

```
➜  ~ curl -X POST 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/users' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": 56,
    "name": "user56",
    "age": 156
}' | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   234  100   180  100    54   3600   1080 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4680
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "user1",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "user1",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "user1",
      "age": 10
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "user5",
      "age": 15
    },
    {
      "id": 56,
      "name": "user56",
      "age": 156
    }
  ]
}
```